# Annotate Outliers on Seaborn Jointplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Graphing the "tips" dataset as jointplot, I would like to label the top 10 outliers (or top-n outliers) on the graph by their indexes from the "tips" dataframe.  I compute the residual (a point's distance from average line) for finding the outliers.  Please ignore the merits of this outlier detection method.  I just want to annotate the graph according to spec.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid", color_codes=True)

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
model = pd.ols(y=tips.tip, x=tips.total_bill)
tips['resid'] = model.resid

#indices to annotate
tips.sort_values(by=['resid'], ascending=[False]).head(5)
```

[image]

```
tips.sort_values(by=['resid'], ascending=[False]).tail(5)
```

[image]

```
%matplotlib inline
g = sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips, kind="reg",
                  xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 12), color="r", size=7)
```

How do I annotate the top 10 outliers (largest 5 and smallest 5 residuals) on the graph by each point's index value (largest residuals) to have this:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use matplotlib `annotate` to create an annotation to a point. The idea is to iterate over the dataframes and place an annotation at the respective position given by the `"tip"` and `"total_bill"` column.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="darkgrid", color_codes=True)

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
model = pd.ols(y=tips.tip, x=tips.total_bill)
tips['resid'] = model.resid

g = sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips, kind="reg",
                  xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 12), color="r", size=7)

#indices to annotate
head = tips.sort_values(by=['resid'], ascending=[False]).head(5)

tail = tips.sort_values(by=['resid'], ascending=[False]).tail(5)

def ann(row):
    ind = row[0]
    r = row[1]
    plt.gca().annotate(ind, xy=(r["total_bill"], r["tip"]), 
            xytext=(2,2) , textcoords ="offset points", )

for row in head.iterrows():
    ann(row)
for row in tail.iterrows():
    ann(row)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Note that as of pandas version 0.20 the `pandas.ols` [has been removed](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-prior-deprecations). To replace it, one may use the [OLS model](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS) from `statsmodels`. The respective lines would then read:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
model = sm.OLS(tips.tip, tips.total_bill)
tips['resid'] = model.fit().resid
```

Note that the result is slightly different (probably due to different weighting).

Comment: sorting and truncating the iterables `head` and `tail` was a nice way to cut the number of iterations, esp for large dataframes like my actual dataset.  thanks

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution for newer versions of pandas.